# Using BCGControlBar in MFC Extension DLL

Tags: c++, mfc, bcg

I'm working on the MFC Extension DLL which exposes the only CDialog class. That dialog is a piece of common UI that a number of other applications use. All of those applications do use BCGControlBar so it's necessary to make the dialog in DLL look like GUI of calling applications.

It's clear how to use BCG with stand-alone application (lots of examples provided), however, it's not clear how to use it with MFC Extension DLL.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like there is no rocket science needed.

Just including the BCGCBProInc.h into the StdAfx.h of MFC Extension DLL and making sure that the linker would find pre-compiled BCG library. Main application starts, loads the extension DLL and everything just works.

Comment: Should be mentioned that you are forced to use the same BCG DLL version  in the extension DLL as used in the EXE. The BCG must be completely initialized.... this is the case as noted in the question.